# How to replicate `apply()` using summarise() from dplyr

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain my EXPECTED OUTPUT (below) using `summarise()` from `tidyverse`?

In other words, how to make `stat2`'s output to look like `EXPECTED_OUTPUT`?

```
library(tidyverse)

th <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/d/master/ths.csv')

EXPECTED_OUTPUT <- data.frame(t(apply(th, 2, function(x) c(median(x), IQR(x)))))

stat2 <- summarise(th, across(.fns = list(median=median, IQR=IQR)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try reshaping the data like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

th <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/d/master/ths.csv')

EXPECTED_OUTPUT <- data.frame(t(apply(th, 2, function(x) c(median(x), IQR(x)))))

stat2 <- summarise(th, across(.fns = list(median=median, IQR=IQR))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% separate(name,c('Var','Measure'),sep='_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Measure,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 60 x 3
   Var    median   IQR
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 item1       6     1
 2 item2       5     1
 3 item3       5     1
 4 item4       5     2
 5 item5       6     0
 6 item6       7     2
 7 item7       5     3
 8 item8       7     4
 9 item9       6     5
10 item10      6     2
# ... with 50 more rows
```

The other option would be:

```
#Code 2
stat2 <- th %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% summarise(median=median(value), IQR=IQR(value))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 60 x 3
   name   median   IQR
   <chr>   <int> <dbl>
 1 item1       6     1
 2 item10      6     2
 3 item11      8    10
 4 item12      1    10
 5 item13      6     2
 6 item14      6     2
 7 item15      6     0
 8 item16      5     2
 9 item17      7     3
10 item18      7     3
# ... with 50 more rows
```

Comment: @rnorouzian I have added an update with reshape directly and summarise, so that it can be seen more elegant. I hope that helps you!

Comment: @rnorouzian Sometimes reshaping the data is the key to obtain the expected result. Maybe our sight with loops or other complex things forces us to try complex things but reshaping simplify a ton of work!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you adjust the raw data directly:

```
th %>%
  rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(median = median(value),
            IQR = IQR(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
out <- data.table::transpose(setDT(th)[, lapply(.SD,
       function(x) c(median(x), IQR(x)))], keep.names = 'Var')
```

---

Or using `base R` in a single line

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, stack(th)[2:1], function(x) c(median(x), IQR(x)))
```